# Improving Tesseract OCR accuracy for patent images in Python

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I'm using pytesseract to OCR patent images to turn these old patents into machine readable text.  An example image I use is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Kz5NTvWjJub2hhYzA2SEpSeUE).  The output is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Kz5NTvWjJuazcwSVg4ZEt5RW8).  Basically I'm doing it fairly simply.  My relevant code is this:

```
for each4 in listoffiles:#in list of files get all text into text using tesseract    
        im = Image.open(path2+'\\'+each4)
        text = text + pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
```

I have experimented a little with modifying the the config file but the only improvement I found was by white-listing [a-zA-Z0-9,.].  I haven't modified the code yet to take into account the config file, as performance is not yet up to my standards.  There are so many options I feel like a missed a lot though, so any other suggestions on config file modification would be helpful.

I see from other suggestions to use OpenCV, ndimage, and skimage for python.  I am quite inexperienced in computer vision so I wouldn't know where to start with these packages for my problems and guidance would be appreciated.

Other options I am thinking of include using Tesseract 4.0 and training the OCR on my own on patents/adding specific patent related words to the dictionary.  Don't know what I should prioritize, but if you have suggestions, luckily I possess the rare ability to read readme files (actually not entirely true, but I will try my best).